# How do I do a Login query?

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

when I use this code:

```
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_REGISTER + 
  " where email="+userInfo.getUsername()+" && password="+userInfo.getLoginPass();
SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);
long count = statement.simpleQueryForLong();
```

I get this error message:

```
02-29 20:36:27.864: E/AndroidRuntime(461): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: abcdefg: , while compiling: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM register where email=abcdefg and password=aaaaa
02-29 20:36:27.864: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
02-29 20:36:27.864: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
02-29 20:36:27.864: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
02-29 20:36:27.864: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
02-29 20:36:27.864: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:36)
02-29 20:36:27.864: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1145)
02-29 20:36:27.864: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at com.lifeApp.RegisterProcessing.loginUser(RegisterProcessing.java:173)
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: For the sake of users of your app, I hope you aren't actually keeping the plain-text password in your database. You definitely need to hash it. For more info, see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Hashing_Java

Answer (score 1):

The error you receive is due to the fact that the sql statement is missing the quotes "'". Anyhow, there's no meaning in using prepared statements like that. You have to bind parameters later. Try this (I haven't tried myself so I apologize for any mistake):

```
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_REGISTER + " where email= ? and password= ?";
SQLiteStatement stmt = database.compileStatement(sql);
stmt.bindString(1, userInfo.getUsername());
stmt.bindString(2, userInfo.getLoginPass());
stmt.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

String literals should be inside single quotes.

```
 String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_REGISTER + " where email= '"+userInfo.getUsername()+"' && password= '"+userInfo.getLoginPass()+"'";
```

Comment: Better avoid doing this, use prepared statements instead. Code like this with unsanitized input leads to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.